# ADFS 2.0 single sign out fails after multiple signin and signout

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs2.0

Hi I am facing following issue for single sign out in ADFS 2.0.

I am using ADFS 2.0 as RSTS
Another ADFS 2.0 is registered as claim provider and is configured for Forms authentication.

I have 4 relying parties (RPs) hosted on another IIS server m/c.

I am opening all the 4 RPs in IE after authenticating against Claim Provider. Sign-out works perfectly fine for the first time. But if I sign-in again and click on sign-out ,any one of the RP application remains signed-in after refresh.I could also see the Auth cookie remaining there after sign-out is processed by the ADFS/LS site.

Note: single sign-out work correctly for multiple sign-in and sign-out if the count of RP apps is restricted up to 3.

Am I missing any settings in RSTS?
How R-STS remembers all the RPs for which it's creating the signout cleanup request (wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0)?
If it's a known issue in ADFS2.0, is it resolved in higher version of ADFS (3.0) any guess?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the work around and mentioned the details [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b63a9092-71f6-4dab-adad-45462016e07b/adfs-20-single-sign-out-fails-after-multiple-signin-and-signout?forum=Geneva&prof=required) , but still following questions need some light

1)why that R-STS's adfs/ls site does snot sign-out one or more RP app(s) for multiple sign-in , sign-out. Is it like R-STS's adfs/ls site is randomly loosing one or more RP url in this case?

2)How R-STS's adfs/ls site is maintaining the RPs url and why single sign out does not work in case of multiple sign-in , sign-out without closing the browser?

3) Is this a known bug and is it fixed in higher version of ADFS say 3.0? or any thing I am missing in handling the single sign out?